# In SQL Server, how to pick top 4th row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

What is the SQL query to pick top 4th row for every Id# ?

It is not Top 4 row of records. I am trying to pick only 4th row of record / column for every id.

Comment: Are the rows ordered in ascending or descending order? Can you please give an example of how the output should be.

Comment: Every Bill Id has several lines of Transactions. I need to pick only 4th line from the Top.

Comment: If you are using MySQL then there is limit clause to set offset n number of rows retrieved

Comment: I am trying to get the query on SQL 2008

Answer (score 7):

Use the `row_number` function:

```
With cte as
(
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rownum
    from 
        table 
)
select * 
from cte 
where rownum = 4
```

Change order by in partition according to your definition of top

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query and pass the required ID of the table to get the specific 4th row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         m.CityId, m.Country, m.Location, m.NoofDweller, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Country ASC) AS RowNumber 
     FROM 
         Cities m 
     WHERE 
         m.Country = 3 -- Just pass the required ID of the table 
    ) AS Details
WHERE 
    RowNumber = 4 -- Gets details of the 4th row of the given ID
```